# Contiouse Crawl and Incremental crawl, both require adding a schedule. So what are the differences

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am setting my search service in 2013. I have noticed that when I select "Enable Continuous Crawl" & "Enable Incremental Crawl"; both are asking to specify the Schedule for the crawl!

What are the main differences between the two, as both require a schedule to run and the scheduled can vary according to user preferences?

Answer (score 4):

The schedule specified when configuring a continuous crawl is the "clean up" crawl. Default 4 hours.
Continuous crawl ignores errors during the crawl, and does not retry the 'bad' url/item and the cleanup crawl takes care of that, just as a normal incremental crawl.

The big difference between continuous crawls,and incremental crawls are that continuous crawls can run in parallel (if the previously started ones hasn't finished) whereas incremental crawls runs sequentially.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so whatever i specify in the schedule for the continuous crawl , will not affect how often it run.? and the drop down will specify the clean up crawl and not the actual execution for the continuous crawl.??

Comment: Continous crawl runs every 15th minute by default. Use PoSh to configure the "ContinuousCrawlInterval" property on the SSA to set a custom crawl interval for continous crawl.